# Get date of birth from the South Africa id number in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Date of birth not updated when editing the id number. Please see the code below I might be doing something. looks like it updates the state first and then on the second click it update the dob.

```
 dob = () => {
    const { idNumber } = this.state.user;
    if (idNumber.length !== 0) {
      let year;
      const dd = Number(idNumber.substring(4, 6));
      const mm = Number(idNumber.substring(2, 4));
      year = idNumber[0] <= 1 ? Number(20 + idNumber.substring(0, 2)) : Number(19 + idNumber.substring(0, 2));
      const formatMonthAndDay = (value, figures) => (value.toString()).padStart(2, '0');
      const day = formatMonthAndDay(dd, 2);
      const month = formatMonthAndDay(mm, 2);
      console.log('DOB ', year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
      return  year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    }
  }
  handleChange = async (event) => {
    if (event.target) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { target: { name, value }, } = event;
      this.setState({
        user: {
          ...this.state.user,
          [name]: value,
          dateOfBirth: this.dob(),
        },
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Stands for South Africa

Comment: Since you can always compute the date of birth from the ID number, you shouldn't be storing it in the state at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You're seeing how `setState` is asynchronous.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) `this.state` hasn't got the chance to update before `this.dob()` requires it.

However, as my comment says, since the DOB is always computable from the ID number, don't store it in the state at all.
(You could use `React.memo()` if the computation was more intensive, but here it doesn't matter.)

```js
const computeDOB = (idNumber) => {
  if (idNumber.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let year;
  const dd = Number(idNumber.substring(4, 6));
  const mm = Number(idNumber.substring(2, 4));
  year = idNumber[0] <= 1 ? Number(20 + idNumber.substring(0, 2)) : Number(19 + idNumber.substring(0, 2));
  const formatMonthAndDay = (value, figures) => value.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const day = formatMonthAndDay(dd, 2);
  const month = formatMonthAndDay(mm, 2);
  console.log("DOB ", year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
  return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      user: {
        idNumber: "",
      },
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const {
        target: { name, value },
      } = event;
      this.setState({
        user: {
          ...this.state.user,
          [name]: value,
        },
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input name="idNumber" placeholder="SA ID number" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <br />
        {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
        <br />
        {computeDOB(this.state.user.idNumber)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

setState is asynchronous. componentDidUpdate can be used to react to a change in state.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sun-f0ig7?file=/src/App.js:0-1303)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      user: {
        idNumber: ""
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
    if (this.state.user.idNumber !== prevState.user.idNumber) {
      this.dob();
    }
  }

  dob = () => {
    const { idNumber } = this.state.user;
    if (idNumber.length !== 0) {
      let year;
      const dd = Number(idNumber.substring(4, 6));
      const mm = Number(idNumber.substring(2, 4));
      year =
        idNumber[0] <= 1
          ? Number(20 + idNumber.substring(0, 2))
          : Number(19 + idNumber.substring(0, 2));
      const formatMonthAndDay = (value, figures) =>
        value.toString().padStart(2, "0");
      const day = formatMonthAndDay(dd, 2);
      const month = formatMonthAndDay(mm, 2);
      console.log("DOB ", year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
      const dob = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

      this.setState({
        user: {
          ...this.state.user,
          dateOfBirth: dob
        }
      });
    }
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    if (event.target) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const {
        target: { name, value }
      } = event;
      this.setState({
        user: {
          ...this.state.user,
          [name]: value,
        }
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input name="idNumber" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not work when you paste the input and when you edit the id number, it updates the date of birth on the second click. Try to edit the input and watch the console.